# http://localhost:8080 does not appear?

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat7

I'm running [Tomcat 7 server](https://tomcat.apache.org/download-70.cgi) in eclipse. This is working fine but `http://localhost:8080` is not popping up! Please help me I'm new to eclipse and server programming.

my console status:

```
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server version:        Apache Tomcat/7.0.70
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server built:          Jun 15 2016 16:27:45 UTC
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Server number:         7.0.70.0
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Name:               Windows 8
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: OS Version:            6.2
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Architecture:          x86
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Java Home:             C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Version:           1.8.0_102-b14
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: JVM Vendor:            Oracle Corporation
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_BASE:         D:\testingp\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: CATALINA_HOME:         D:\testingp\apache-tomcat-7.0.70-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.70
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.base=D:\testingp\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dcatalina.home=D:\testingp\apache-tomcat-7.0.70-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.70
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dwtp.deploy=D:\testingp\.metadata\.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp2\wtpwebapps
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Djava.endorsed.dirs=D:\testingp\apache-tomcat-7.0.70-windows-x86\apache-tomcat-7.0.70\endorsed
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.VersionLoggerListener log
INFO: Command line argument: -Dfile.encoding=Cp1252
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener lifecycleEvent
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_102\bin;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/bin/client;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/bin;C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_102/lib/i386;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_92\bin;<path-to-sdk>/platform-tools;C:\Users\MISSION ANDROID\Desktop\;C:\Users\MISSION ANDROID\Downloads\Compressed\eclipse-jee-indigo-SR2-win32\eclipse;;.
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:27 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:27 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 767 ms
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:27 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.70
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.TldConfig execute
INFO: At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:28 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGeneratorBase createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [220] milliseconds.
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8080"]
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:28 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Jul 30, 2016 7:42:28 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 687 ms
```

and deploy path is by default:

```
"wtpwebapps"
```

Comment: `http://localhost:8080 is not popup`. What is that supposed to mean ? You should just need to open your browser and type http://localhost:8080. If there is a server running on port 8080 this will definitely work

Comment: @Dici only http://localhost:8080 ??

Comment: Yup, the browser will add the http part itself, but both should work

Comment: @Dici it shows 404 error

Comment: @xyzrety - That means your Tomcat is running.  Your next problem is to figure out what the URL should be to get to your webapp.  Obviously an empty path is wrong.  (The 404 response means "not found").

Comment: @Dici: I assume "is not popup" means "doesn't show up".

Comment: Have you ever tried to start the `Tomcat` directly and visit `http://localhost:8080`?